# What training would prepare you to colonize Alpha Centauri Cb?

Tags: planets, science-fiction, space-colonization

It's 100 years in the future. 7 strategic, catastrophic bombs fell on Earth 55 years ago. Billions died. Countries, governments collapsed. Corporations rose, mega-companies who rule the world, relatively benignly (for them to thrive, so must their workers/benefactors).

One of The Big Four, ("The Company"), has developed a proprietary engine that can travel to Alpha Centauri Cb, where a small population of pioneers has begun to set up infrastructure. In order to survive the journey, Voyagers are placed in cryostasis and awoken upon arrival.

Given that:

- We assume these [habitable conditions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/252939/how-might-seasons-work-on-alpha-centauri-cb)
- Due to the nuclear winter and the subsequent rise in corporation control, and consumer dependency, "real food" is more expensive than manufactured equivalents, and so it is assumed any preparing Voyagers (whose parents were young children when the bombs fell) will need rigorous nutritional and physical training
- The only candidates eligible for this tremendously expensive journey
  have a genetic mutation that render them resistant to radiation
  damage (à la tardigrades), and yet cosmic storms are a health risk on Cb
- Cb contains edible flora and fauna that supply sufficient nutrition, though a far narrower cuisine than Earth's occupants
- Population is currently 12; with the 8 newest Voyagers who require training, that will make 20.
- All are required either as surrogates or providers/contribute support, and wear more than one hat
- While there is some tech, supplies and materials available from Earth are only what can fit inside a lean, mean rocket carrying 8 in cryo
- Rockets only arrive every 4 years, with another 8 Voyagers, and leave within a week full of payload (see below). There's no Home Depot for random supplies.
- The cost of human return is far too expensive, so this is a one-way
  trip.
- There is NO wood, or crude oil on Cb. Primary energy sources are geothermal and solar. Grass is plentiful, so basketweaving is (ironically) a valued skill
- Nothing from Earth will germinate on Cb, so a basic knowledge of biology and a working knowledge of Cb's flora and fauna is essential.
- Some rustic "pioneer" skills such as manual labour/repair, etc. are desirable, and yet this generation is used to an automated metropolis
- The Company requires a payload of rare ore, metals, minerals. Miners are the breadwinners here. All other occupations in health care, farming, surrogacy etc. are for the growth and support of the community, but mining's the ultimate goal (yes, this is an exo-planet version of the Klondike Gold Rush!)
- (edited to add) Travel and communications are FTL!

**What training would our intrepid Voyagers need to adjust, adapt, and achieve a purposeful life on Cb? Some skills would obviously require far more education than others, such as doctors or engineers. The 8 selected will have been chosen for their complementary skills. Are there some "universal" aspects to training they would all benefit from, experienced as a group within a 3-month training program? Keep in mind, they're in cryo for the entire journey, so they need almost no space-related education, unless it pertains to their new life on Cb.**

*Spitballing: basic mechanics? CPR? Psychological counselling?*

---

Edited to answer @KerrAvon2055's questions:

Currently on planet:

- 1 geneticist/general scientist
- 2 engineers
- 2 communication techs (constant send/receive data back to Earth)
- 2 mechanic/fabricators
- 1 general builder
- 1 doctor
- 1 miner
- 1 farmer
- 1 surrogate with general skills

The 8 about to travel:

- 1 farmer
- 1 nurse
- 1 lab tech
- 1 scientist
- 2 surrogates with general skills
- 1 musician, also a surrogate with general skills (main character)

I haven't explored much in the way of geothermal power equipment requirements, or mining.

I have accounted for 4 farmers to feed 20, though everyone ought to have a basic knowledge of local fauna. One major limitation, which I forgot but will list above also, is that, for reasons unknown (until the midpoint), nothing from Earth will germinate on Cb.

No nanotech here. Drones provide security footage.

There is strong computational processing power, much in the way of 3-D modelling, data processing, file compressing. 3-D printing highly advanced, but the building materials are finite; only what they flew in with, and what can be recycled & re-printed.

This is the interesting tension; a technologically advanced corporation sends the best of its society to reap exorbitant rewards, but to do so it relies on manual labour, crude conditions, and social cooperation, light years from Earth.

---

Second edit:

Thanks to several helpful comments and answers, I acknowledge that the mining angle is uneconomical given my other parameters. Even if I wanted to follow an *Avatar* vein of "unobtanium", that would require highly specialized infrastructure and too much manpower.

A biological target would be much more feasible, and more in line with the "grassroots" nature of this young colony.

Something along the lines of a [panacea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panacea_(medicine)) might be more realistic.

Comment: What skills and equipment do the 12 people already present have?  (On a tight mass budget, how have they possibly set up geothermal power?)  What mining equipment is being provided?  (No point training to operate a bulldozer if pick and shovel are the best available.)  How many people are needed to grow, harvest and/or hunt food?  What are the limits of robots/computers/nanotech that require human workers?

Comment: These are fair questions @KerrAvon2055. I will edit the post in response.

Comment: This seems a bit too story-based. WB.SE is here to help building your world, not to think of plot details.

Comment: As it stands - unless you want to add context - Scientists are a luxury your colony can't afford - in terms of manhours and resources. Unless by Scientist you either mean a Mining Geologist. A nurse is also a luxury, esp cause all of them would have basic first aid.

Comment: Unless there's a lot of tech that's being glossed over that would make all of this easier, there's no chance that one miner, confined to one settlement, could produce enough of value to justify the trip.

Comment: Thank you @KerrAvon2055 and @ TheDemonLord, @ jdunlop-- these are all valid points. 

Respectfully, @ value1, these details like figuring out what roles are needed to build my world, that's world-building =) You are right in that the roles are plot-related too, but I am grateful for the insight of others to help me world-build believably, to the future benefit of a better plot.

Comment: Am i understanding this correctly, the payoff McGuffin to the sponsor is a return load from Alpha Centauri is metal? Like regular bog standard stuff found on the periodic table? Stuff that is found in the sol system?

Comment: @GaultDrakkor TBH the payoff McGuffin, as you coin it, is TBD but is NOT something you could find in our sol system. Eg. a new element, or the elixir of youth =) for the cost of the return trip, it's gotta be something special!

Comment: @reiterwriter The term MacGuffin  was popularized by Alfred Hitchcock apparently. There is a lot of difference between biological target and mineral target as to what personnel are needed and extraction techniques. Also you should have been explicit that the engine and communications are FTL.

Comment: For future reference, please be aware that we have a love-hate relationship with "what skills do they need?" questions. By definition they're Too Story-Based as the specific skill set will be determined by the circumstances of your story. There isn't a single skill set that's perfect for all plot twists. About half the time these questions are closed. Frankly, I can justify any skill you can think of as useful in the environment you've described. Even hair styling. Consequently, the goal of your question is very important. What *specific* problem are you trying to overcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the question of what a minimal skill set would be for any post-apocalyptic situation, except there is no pre-existing technological equipment to cannibalize.

The sponsor cares about return shipments of mined products, and refined products as well. An ore typically has a small percentage of the desired product, so local refining would have a large value-add to the colony.  The question stipulates that one of the products returned is "metals".  On earth, there were tiny amounts of metal naturally found (gold nuggets), but essentially all metals require refinement with large energy and chemical inputs.  Obtaining these inputs would be a key need, so someone with knowledge and experience in process engineering would be valuable.

Any process equipment is likely to require metals, pipes, heaters, distillers, cleaners, and so on, all of which need to be fabricated.  It would help to know more about the refinement processes that the colonists would need to support.

I will assume that the "surrogates" are there to provide uterine space to gestate babies. This will require that the new colonists be educated to the level needed for their work.  We could have the new colonists only be used for manual labor, but there would still be a few years of protection and basic teaching that would be needed before they could be used.  With a small population, the number of new colonists produced will be low (at most, about 4 per Earth year per surrogate), so in the beginning, the intrinsic population growth will be similar to the extrinsic growth.  What does this mean for the politics of the colony, and the power dynamics?

Of the people currently in the population, there seems to be too many communication techs.  It is a long latency communication, that wouldn't carry much information.  Maybe they could increase the back-link data needs by doing a reality-show live transmittal of all aspects of life on the colony, and selling the video as earth-side entertainment, but two residents with their primary focus on communications seems high.

I would suggest that the engineers be focused on geo-engineering and materials engineering.  Knowing where to dig, and how to process what is dug.  You don't have a large enough population to support complex product development, or even programming.  You will need to make pipe, but not computation engines.

Comment: this is exceptionally helpful, TY. You answered in a way that I did not expect, but you're right: if the sponsor desires refined products, there needs to be support for that. 

As for the surrogates' "usefulness", yes they are there to gestate babies, but babies of a certain kind (as that's getting into plot territory, I shan't digress). 

As for the reality-show live transmittal... clever you, that happens to be a major plot point =) hence the need for 2 comm techs. 

Again, TY very much for engaging fully with my question. It has given me many productive questions to consider.

Answer (score 1):

##### Assumption: FTL engines

If the engines were not FTL, the project would be absurdly uneconomical.

- The cost to construct the rockets/space ships, probably hundreds of billions to trillions USD.
  The opportunity cost would be substantial.
- The time cost to arrive and start extraction, probably over 60 years one way.
- The time to extract resources for a load probably decades, thats assuming they don't have to refuel the rocket.
- Would have much less information then what is given in the question.
- Complications setting up the colony.

### Given FTL engines.

Assuming previously unknown mineral resource such as Avatar's unobtainium.

There are still very large problems.

##### Finding a deposit.

Assuming difficulties similar to copper. A crew of 10 would be reasonable as a mineral exploration team that could take a decade to find a suitable deposit.

That is, Air born surveys would be very helpful. no equipment or crew is listed to do that. Ground based geophysics. Drilling of targets. Lab analysis of samples. Granted not all of these would be full time occupations, but while active they would be a dozen people 56 hours/week type jobs.

Implies personal: Aircraft or drone pilot. Prospector. Driller, Geophysicist, Geologist, Lab technician.

##### Deposit found.

Very specific heavy machinery is needed to be able to extract the ore. In worst case disseminated implies that many tonnes of rock need to be processed per gram. Which is very energy intense, and requires a lot of heavy equipment.
If the mineral forms veins extraction is considerably faster. Plus production of chemicals used in extraction. Cranes to construct certain components.

Implies personnel:
Miner, machine operators, heavy duty mechanic, instrument mechanic, explosive technicians, process chemist, Construction personnel to construct the processing plant and various managers.

##### Energy.

Miners are very energy intense. So solar might be used to augment but primary will be a few large nuclear fusion power plants. Geothermal is not worth considering because where the minerals are is not necessarily where the geothermal is.

Implied personnel:
plant operators, technicians.

##### Food supply.

If earth plants don't grow in the native soil that implies hydroponics. That will need a lot of automation or few people as well.

Implied personnel: Farmer, technicians. process chemist.

##### Operations.

No mention is made of managers.
It is by far best to have explicit team in charge. keeping things running such as cooks and medical personnel.

Implied personal managers, cook, doctor.

Note:
by technician I mean people that don't necessarily have specific degree. but are trained enough to do maintenance and other operations for their assigned task. Operator are personal who have a relevant degree and have a few years of experience operating the equipment.

##### Return trip.

With shipping tonnes of material back to Sol. An eventual return trip is a reasonable expectation. That is, the one way idea should be dropped or the quality of employee will drop or those that are willing to go, are going for ulterior motives.ie wont' care much about the companies priorities.

##### Energy.

Miners are very energy intense. So solar might be used to augment but primary will be a few large nuclear fusion power plants. Geothermal is not worth considering because where the minerals are is not necessarily where the geothermal is.

Implied personnel: operator and technician.

#### Conclusion

There will likely be people in multiple roles, which costs efficiency. A sizable mine would be expected to have hundreds of personnel.  To operate in a profitable manner there should be many more personnel so that economies of scale kick in to drop the cost per tonne of extracted mineral.

Comment: TY for this excellent, logical response. I think your answer is redefining my question; you and other responders have ruled out the feasibility of mining, within my desired world parameters. I am going to edit the original question to note that a biological payload, rather than a mineral one, is more plausible.